# How do I create a timeline with text that can "skip ahead" to a desired start week?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to make a timeline that can auto-populate a cell contents based on which week they should begin. I would like to provide excel with information like this....

| Task | First Week | Second Week | 3rd Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | 40 | 40 | 20 |
| Project 2 | 20 | 40 | 40 |

Then I want be able to see this as a timeline once I enter the "start week" info.

| Task | Start Week | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | Week 4 | Week 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | 1 | 40 | 40 | 20 |  |  |
| Project 2 | 3 |  |  | 20 | 40 | 40 |

I tried working with XLOOKUP, IF, and OFFSET, and got a lot of "SPILL" errors. Thanks for you help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an IF and INDEX/MATCH and some math:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A$1)<$H2,"",IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$D$3,MATCH($G2,$A$2:$A$3,0),COLUMN(A$1)-$H2+1),""))
```

That goes in I2 then copy/drag over and down.

[image]